# Azure App Services Deployment Slot Transformations

Tags: azure, transformation, webdeploy, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I would like to start using the deployment slots in my Azure App Services for a staging to production task.  The problem that I am running into is I can't seem to find a way to do transformations on the web.config outside of the appsetting and connectionstrings.  I seem to be missing something, but I need to be able to adjust other configurations, from logging levels, to other integrated config sections.

We currently have been using direct deployments from our build server with msdeploy and Parameters.xml file to do much of this work, however that won't work with deployment slots.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the additional deployment slot, you can clone all settings from the existing instance, or dont copy anything. [As per documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots):

> "*You can clone configuration from any existing slot. Settings that can
>   be cloned include app settings, connection strings, language framework
>   versions, web sockets, HTTP version, and platform bitness.*"

In the new deployment slot, under Settings > Configuration, you can specify any settings here to be specific to the new deployment slot by selecting "Deployment slot setting".